# How do check if PDO object is connected properly inside a different class?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to fetch some information from my mysql database in a class, so I'm passing in the PDO object into a `__construct` function, and working from there. However, what's an elegant way of checking to see if <strike>the PDO object was correctly created, and that</strike> the connection is open when the `Table` class is instantiated?

```
class Table{

    public function __construct(PDO $db, $week){

        try{
            $query = $db -> query ("SELECT * FROM `table1` where `day` = 'monday'");

        }
        catch(PDOExeption $e){
            echo 'error: '. $e->getMessage();
            //die();        
        }
    } 

}
```

I don't think this code does what I want.

Comment: Maybe you should check it not in `Table` class but in moment where you trying to connect with DB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no need for such a verification.

If PDO object was created incorrectly and no connection were opened, **an exception would be thrown**, and thus script will be halted before calling any class' method.

Comment: +1 The PDO object [will not even get returned](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php)

Comment: Ah, maybe I wasn't clear. What if another function in my application decides to close the connection? Then when I create an instance of my `Table` class, it won't know if it's connected or not...

Comment: Just don't bother with closing it.